# Extract the match positions in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I can easily extract the start/end positions of strings in text using `re.finditer`resulting in tuples of the start/end positions of the matches.

```
s1 = 'the quick quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
s2 = 'Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs'
s3 = 'How razorback jumping frogs can level six piqued gymnasts'

r1 = '(quick|fox|dog)'
r2 = '(box|five|jugs)'
r3 = '(frogs|six)'

t = [(s1,r1), (s2,r2), (s3,r3)]


for e in t:
    print([(f.start(), f.end()) for f in re.finditer(e[1],e[0])])
```

---

```
[(4, 9), (10, 15), (22, 25), (46, 49)]
[(8, 11), (17, 21), (35, 39)]
[(22, 27), (38, 41)]
```

I have a DataFrame with text in one column and regex's in another

```
s = pd.DataFrame(data={'re':[r1,r2,r3], 'text':[s1,s2,s3]})
```

---

```
    re              text
0   (quick|fox|dog) the quick quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
1   (box|five|jugs) Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs
2   (frogs|six)     How razorback jumping frogs can level six piqu...
```

I would like to extract the same position information into a `Series` object using `pandas.str` methods but there isn't a `finditer` method (in pandas 0.23).

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a for-each loop?

Comment: Using a list comprehension usually is faster than using pandas string methods.

Comment: @user3483203 Do you mean like this: `[(mo.start(), mo.end()) for r in s.re for text in s.text.values for mo in re.finditer(r, text)]`. This gives the values back alright but they're mixed into a single list. How can I separate each set for a given text/re pair?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @Daniel The output would be a Series object with the values shown above `[(4, 9), (10, 15), (22,25), (46, 49)]` in the first row, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @user3483203 comment, you could do the following using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s1 = 'the quick quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
s2 = 'Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs'
s3 = 'How razorback jumping frogs can level six piqued gymnasts'

r1 = '(quick|fox|dog)'
r2 = '(box|five|jugs)'
r3 = '(frogs|six)'

t = [(s1,r1), (s2,r2), (s3,r3)]

s = pd.DataFrame(data={'re':[r1,r2,r3], 'text':[s1,s2,s3]})

result = pd.Series([[(f.start(), f.end()) for f in re.finditer(p, s)] for p, s in zip(s.re, s.text)])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    [(4, 9), (10, 15), (22, 25), (46, 49)]
1             [(8, 11), (17, 21), (35, 39)]
2                      [(22, 27), (38, 41)]
dtype: object
```

Another alternative, will be to use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but I believe this could be slower:

```
def finditer(p, s):
    return [(f.start(), f.end()) for f in re.finditer(p, s)]


result = s[['re', 'text']].apply(lambda x: finditer(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
print(result)
```

Comment: timings below  :

Comment: `print(timeit.timeit('pd.Series([[(f.start(), f.end()) for f in re.finditer(p, s)] for p, s in zip(s.re, s.text)])', setup=setup, number=10000))` **1.3337575541809201**

Comment: `print(timeit.timeit("s[['re', 'text']].apply(lambda x:  [(f.start(), f.end()) for f in re.finditer(x[0], x[1])], axis=1)", setup=setup, number=10000))` **11.1610545986332**

Comment: `setup = '''
import pandas as pd
import re
s1 = 'the quick quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
s2 = 'Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs'
s3 = 'How razorback jumping frogs can level six piqued gymnasts'

r1 = '(quick|fox|dog)'
r2 = '(box|five|jugs)'
r3 = '(frogs|six)'
s = pd.DataFrame(data={'re':[r1,r2,r3], 'text':[s1,s2,s3]})
'''`

Comment: @hhbilly So using a list comprehension is about 10x times faster?

Comment: @hhbilly Do you want me to include the timings in the answer?